# how to get the id value From one mxml file to another mxml file in flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex

My Apllication is in Flex 3.5...My Code is Here,How to take the id value of textare?
Button.Mxml

```
<mx:Button width="20" height="20" label="TextArea" id="textarea" click="setShape(DrawObject.TEXT);showTextArea()"/>
```

My Another file is here:
Main.Mxml

```
 private function doMouseDown_canvas():void
                    {
                            if(this.shapeStyle==DrawObject.TEXT)
                            {
                                    if(isDrawing)
                                    {
                                            isDrawing = false;
                                            this.d = drawFactory.makeDrawObject(this.shapeStyle,segment, this.drawColor, this.thickness, textarea.text);
                                            dispatchEvent(new Event(BoardMediator.SEND_SHAPE));

                                    textarea.visible = false;
                                    }else
                                    {
                                            isDrawing = true;
                                            x1 = canvas.mouseX;
                                            y1 = canvas.mouseY;
                                            segment.push(x1);
                                            segment.push(y1);

                                            textarea.text = "";
                                    textarea.visible = true;
                                            textarea.x = canvas.mouseX;
                                            textarea.y = canvas.mouseY;
                                            textarea.setFocus();

                                            locateEditor();
                                    }
                            }else
                            {
                                    isDrawing = true;
                                    x1 = canvas.mouseX;
                                    y1 = canvas.mouseY;
                                    segment.push(x1);
                                    segment.push(y1);
                                    canvas.rawChildren.addChild(feedback);
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: Mind making the question clearer? I have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: No clue what the question is either. . .

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the Button.mxml somewhere ...!?
setting the ID of something inside a mxml file, makes this object a public attribute of the corresponding class.

if the `<mx:Button>` is the only thing inside your button.mxml get rid of the ID inside the button.mxml and set it from the outside.

if you have a surrounding container, sth, like a HGroup you can access it from your main like this:

```
<myNS:Button id="myButton" />
```

and in the `fx:Script` tag:

```
myButton.textarea;
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

MxmlOne.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:Button id="myBtn" label="something"/>
</s:Panel>
```

MxmlTwo.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private function someFunc():void
            {
                myPanel.myBtn.label = 'Some label';
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <MxmlOne id="myPanel"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```